# Как проверить содержит ли многомерный массив ключ

Tags: php

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
$entries=array();
$entries[0]["displayname"][0]="Ivan"  ;
$entries[0]["age"][0]=32              ;
$entries[1]["displayname"][0]="Anna"  ;
$entries[1]["age"][0]='24'              ;
$entries[2]["displayname"][0]="Bob"   ;
$entries[2]["age"][0]=29              ;
$entries[3]["displayname"][0]="Stuart";
$entries[3]["age"][0]=42              ;

if (array_key_exists('displayname', $entries)) { echo "YES '$entries'.";   }
```

Но проблема в том что надо обращаться через первый элемент массива. Пытаюсь построить конструкцию ForEach...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($entries as $entry) {
    if (array_key_exists('displayname', $entry)) {
    echo "Массив содержит элемент 'displayname'.";
}
```

Comment: надо было сделать перерыв 5 мин и мозги стали соображать.. :)